# Hibernate Search automatic update of composed fields

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have a Person entity with multiple name related properties (firstName, lastName, title).
All the name related properties should be stored in a single lucene index field "fullName".

```java
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Person {
   ...
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String title;

   @Field(store=Store.NO, index=Index.TOKENIZED)
   public String getFullName() {
      return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + title;
   }
}
```

The only problem I'm facing is to automatically update the fullName in the index when a name related property is updated.

Is there some way to tell Hibernate Search that fullName is a composed field and must be updated when one of the parts changes? Maybe something like this?

```java
@ComposedOf({"firstName", "lastName", "title"})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Person {
   ...
   @Field(name="fullName") String firstName;
   @Field(name="fullName") String lastName;
   @Field(name="fullName") String title;
}
```

This is possible as you have chosen TOKENIZED and I'm assuming your analyzer is set to split the tokens on whitespace as you're adding whitespace to separate them: you can have multiple repetitions of a same field, the result is almost the same as splitting the compound terms
(I say almost as it won't be able to determine ordering of terms in case you need a PhraseQuery looking for a specific order of keywords).

For more complex cases you would use a *ClassBridge* which disables the dirty-checking optimisation which has been annoying you in this case: Hibernate Search tracks if any persistent field was actually written to to decide if it can skip expensive reindexing operations but is then unable to detect such tricks.

Comment: Nice! This perfectly fits my needs. I always thought the name must be unique.

Answer (score 3):

There are several solutions for your problem and it the solution you are choosing is probably a matter of taste (you might also apply a combination of them):

1. Check the property _hibernate.search.​enable_dirty_check_ and make it sure it is set to *false* in your case. The default is *true*. See the online docs for more information - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/
2. Add the *@Field* annotation also to firstName, lastName and title. You get a bigger index size, but often that does not matter. As a side effect the dirty checking will work (assuming btw that your JPA annotations are correct. For example I am assuming getFullName is transient)
3. Use a class bridge and optionally remove *getFullName*. Using a class bridge will also automatically disable the dirty check optimisation

Comment: Good options. I knew about class bridges but thought they would be a little bit overkill for my simple need. Disable dirty checking globally also seems a bit overkill to me.

I would have preferred indexing all the other fields but finally went with Sannes solution. I also upvoted you're answer. Thanks!